# Why can I call Array.max this way?

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm using Xcode 8.2.1. If I look at the documentation for Array I find this declaration for the `max` method:

`public func max(by areInIncreasingOrder: (Element, Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Element?`

The argument label is `by` and the argument name is `areInIncreasingOrder`. Since the label is specified explicitly I thought it has to be included in a call to the function but the following code works if I omit the label (i.e `by`).

Am I misunderstanding how argument labels are used when calling a method? Or, is my example code calling a different version of the `max` method?

Example code:

```
let names = ["Talyor", "Paul", "Adele"]

let longest = names.max { $1.characters.count > $0.characters.count }
print(longest!)  // "Taylor
```

Comment: And `names.max(by: { $1.characters.count > $0.characters.count })` does compile as expected. What you used is the "trailing closure syntax".

Comment: See the [Trailing Closure](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID102) section of the "The Swift Programming Language" book.

Answer (score 1):

When the last parameter of a method is a closure, you can write it in curly braces *after* the method call and omit the name of the parameter.

See the [Trailing Closure documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID102).